# Print Custom Feature Form using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python

I recently asked a [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104703/pyqgis-print-composer-map-with-table) and accepted the answer, as it was a good guide on accessing the print composer using python. However, I am still looking for a way to print the custom feature form. Does anyone have ideas on how this can be implemented?

I was thinking of a start by using mapCanvas().saveasImage(), but I'm short on ideas as to how to move forward with a screen capture of the feature form.

Comment: I'm interested in the solution of your problem if you finaly got it ? I would like to do exactly the same thing with Qgis 3.4. I thaught we can use a python script in an action of the layer (Layer properties/ Actions). A plugin exists named cReports-master but developed in python 2.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/163116)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/163116)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/163116)