# Adding table to layout using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layouts, table

I need to create a table based on a Python list and paste it in layout view in QGIS.

I also found a `QgsLayoutTable` class in PyQGIS but there's no example of creating a simple table.

If I had these objects:

```
layout = QgsProject.layoutManager().layouts()[0]

table_data = [
  ["a", "b"],
  [1, 2,
]
```

How could I create a QGIS layout table like

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

and add it to the layout?

Comment: Have you checked this article [Print Composer Map with Table using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104703/print-composer-map-with-table-using-pyqgis)?

Comment: @Taras it uses sources of API 2.x, while I need it in 3.X. I have found some tips for creating layout here https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/277223/77806

Comment: Opppss...I did not consider that...